# Chances of admission for a PhD program with high WAM (GPA) for masters but an average GPA for undergraduates (A unique case)

Tags: publications, phd, funding

I have completed a Master of IT specializing in cybersecurity at an Australian University ranked around 200 - 250 in the world for computer science and IT. In my master's, I achieved a Weighted Average Mark of 90.875%  with all HD (higher distinction) grades for the coursework and a thesis mark of 95%. The thesis accounted for 25% of the course.

In addition to all of this, I have two refereed publications (a journal and a conference) of which I am the first author. I am currently working at my master's university as a research assistant.

However, I am still concerned about my bachelor's of Engineering (Computer Engineering) GPA which is average at best. My bachelor's GPA is 3.0/4.0 although I showed significant improvement in the final year of my 4-year bachelor's with a GPA of 3.52/4.0. My bachelor's university has a much lower rank than my master's university.

Could anyone tell me what are my chances of admission to a Ph.D. program? I would also like to know whether I would be competitive for scholarships?

I really hope to pursue a Ph.D. but I am really worried about my bachelor's GPA.

P.S - I have 322/340 for GRE with 168/170 for Quantitative reasoning

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people get into harvard within 3.20 range and I have seen people get rejected with perfect 4.00 from "lesser" schools. From what I have seen it is more about what a transcript / application tells rather than whatever the GPA is. Espcially, you having a masters degree, there are many stories an application could / should tell. I fear no one here would reliably be able to tell you your odds with this amount of information. Even if you disclose every information you have available to yourself, the recommendation letters written about you will have significant implications.

I personally would ask a question like this to my proffesors (with whom I had academical interractions). Your thesis advisor or references would be a good place to start.

Comment: What is your opinion on the information I have provided? Will my master's GPA, publications and GRE score overshadow my undergraduate GPA? (Given that I have strong recommendation letters)

Comment: again, GPA really tells nothing. You can get bunch of low level classes and have a high gpa or really get out of your way to take "risky" courses, actually learn something and somehow prove that you have learned something even though you didn't get an A. I can't say anything specific but my understanding is newer data tend to overshadow the older one.